# Set a TouchableHighlight near CustomDrawer with React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to set my simple TouchableHighlight just near my CustomDrawer but i can't find how to do it . Here is the code .

```
          class App extends Component {

      render() {
      return (
     <View style={{ flex: 1,  flexDirection: 'row',marginTop: (Platform.OS 
       === "ios") ? 20 : 0 }} >

      <View style={styles.container}>
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton}>
      <Image
    style={styles.button}
    source={require('./camera.png')}
     />
       </TouchableHighlight>     
      </View>
        <CustomDrawer
      content={<NavigationMenu />}
      ref="drawerSideMenu"
      onClose={() => { this.props.dispatch(navigationMenuStatus(false)); }}
      onOpen={() => { this.props.dispatch(navigationMenuStatus(true)) }}> 
       <HeaderBar /> 
        </View>
        );
       }
    }


 const styles = StyleSheet.create({

   button: {
   padding: 6,
   height:50,
   width:50
   },
   countContainer: {

      },
      countText: {
      color: '#FF00FF'
    }
    })

  export default Appp
```

Actually i get this as interface but i want to make the button Camera in the blue area near the icon of menu

[image: Picture]

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting the camera icon inside the menu bar.
*something like this*

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.menuBar}>
    <Icon/>
     <Menu/>
   </View>
</View>
```

Comment: i will try it thnxx